# Animation keeps getting triggered when I step on the tiles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games, topdown

I'm developing a TopDown 2D game on Unity with some RPG elements and I did as so, when the player steps on a set of tiles placed on the map, it triggers an animation with a UI showing some text. However, the animation gets called multiple times while the player keeps stepping on the tiles and even when he exits the trigger area.
What I need help with is how to make the animation only trigger once and, while the UI is in on the screen, the player is not allowed to move until the player presses the button in the UI (already programmed and working).
Here is the code I used to make the trigger function:

```
public class TriggerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string popUp;
    public Animator animator;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {       
            PopUpSystem pop = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<PopUpSystem>();
            pop.PopUp(popUp);
            Debug.Log("trigger");
            animator.SetTrigger("pop");

    }
}
```

And here is the PopUpSystem that sets the text:

```
public class PopUpSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject popUpBox;
    public Animator popupanimation;
    public TMP_Text popUpText;
   

    public void PopUp(string text)
    {
        
        
            popUpBox.SetActive(true);
            popUpText.text = text;
            popupanimation.SetTrigger("pop");
            
        
    }
}
```

If, in order to help me, you need more information and details, please ask me in the comment section.

Note that I am new to Unity and have zero experience with it so, if you can be patient and explain things in a simple way, I would enjoy that!

Thank you for reading.

Edit: this is the animator window:

[image]

Edit 2: The code that I use for the movement of the player:

```
public class PLayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D MyRB;
    private Animator myAnim;
    public string popUp;

    [SerializeField]
    private float speed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        MyRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        myAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        myAnim.SetTrigger("popUp");
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        MyRB.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")) * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        
        myAnim.SetFloat("moveX", MyRB.velocity.x);
        myAnim.SetFloat("moveY", MyRB.velocity.y);
        if ((Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal")==1) ||(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") == -1)||(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") == 1)||(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") == -1))
        {
            myAnim.SetFloat("LastMoveX", Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));
            myAnim.SetFloat("LastMoveY", Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        }
    }
    
}
```

Edit 3: Code with boolean:

```
public class TriggerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string popUp;
    public Animator animator;
    bool condition = false;

    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        
    }
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (condition == false)
        {
            PopUpSystem pop = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<PopUpSystem>();
            pop.PopUp(popUp);
            Debug.Log("trigger");
            animator.SetTrigger("pop");
            condition = true;
        }
            
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("close");
    }
```

Comment: Add a script to the tile with the triggering process. When player enters the tile, send the message and disable the trigger script. This way, no chance for multiple calls.

Comment: @Everts How do I disable the trigger script? What is the command?

Comment: In the OnTriggerEnter method, enabled = false

Comment: I did it an nothing happened, It behaved the same.

Comment: I just add ```enabled = false;```? do I have to do more?

Comment: @Everts sry didn't tag u, can u help me plz?

Comment: There may be multiple calls due to multiple contact points. Add a boolean that calls the code only if false. Then set to true in the code so it runs only once.

Comment: @Everts It doesn't work but I may be doing it wrong. Check edit and say what I'm doing wrong plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to set your TriggerScript to something like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TriggerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string popUp;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        PopUpSystem pop = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<PopUpSystem>();
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            pop.PopUp(popUp);
        }
            
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        PopUpSystem pop = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("GameManager").GetComponent<PopUpSystem>();
        pop.closeBox();
    }
}
```

and then set your PopUpSystemScript to something like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;

public class PopUpSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject popUpBox;
    public Animator popupanimation;
    public TMP_Text popUpText;

    public void PopUp(string text)
    {                
        popUpBox.SetActive(true);
        popUpText.text = text;
        popupanimation.SetTrigger("pop");         
    }

    public void closeBox()
    {
        popupanimation.SetTrigger("close"); 
    }
}
```

Now click on the popUp and close animation clips (in Animations folder) and remove the Loop Time check mark. and you should be all set to see the animation appears and disappears.

To stop the player, you can either use Time.timeScale. or set the rigidbody to isKenimatic.

Comment: Can you perhaps talk a bit more on how to flag the animations and what it does? I have no idea what you are talking about xD

Comment: I also don't know how to see if the animation is loping or not. Again, I'm sorry but I'm just new to Unity, it's my first time working with it, hope u can help me and sry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Fine, give me some time.

Comment: Can you show me your animation controller? How many states do you have and what are the transitions? Do your transitions have exit time?

Comment: Check the edit, I think thats what you mean by animation controller.

Comment: I will try to do it and if it doesn't work, I'll reach out to you. Thx for now!

Comment: Do I use that code in the script I use to define the player movement? Cause I already have the walking animation set and initialized. I'm gonna update my post with the code.

Comment: I don't think the bool flag technic would work. I intent the player to stop moving and then the UI pops up on the screen, then the player clicks the button to close the UI and then we can walk again, but he would still be stepping on the trigger tiles.

Comment: Also, I tried to implement the code you gave me and now I have a new error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: No, that is just an example. You have to define it where you use your pop up animation. I can describe it to you further, but right now, I am really busy. We can talk about your problem then.

Comment: Ok I will try to do it.

Comment: I think I already had that done then. Check the 2 code example I gave in the original post, isn't that what u told me to do?

Comment: I added ```animator.SetTrigger("pop");``` to the ```OnTriggerEnter2D``` method and everything is the same, nothing changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228706/discussion-between-hefaz-and-guilherme-oliveira).